# Lenovo touchpad tap doesn't work on kubuntu

Tags: touchpad

I'm on the latest version of kubuntu.  My touchpad mostly works, but what is really annoying is a simple light tap doesn't do anything, where with Windows on here it will do a click.  I've searched and tried different suggestions, none of which have worked.  Is this bug ever going to be fixed?  Is there a fix I can apply, with complete and working instructions?  Many thanks for any help and assistance.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser                 id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Rear Camera                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The xinput changed after reboot, the touchpad is now 9.  Not sure why that isn't staying consistent.  Below is xinput list-props 9

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
        Device Enabled (144):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (146): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Tapping Enabled (279): 0
        libinput Tapping Enabled Default (280): 0
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (281):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (282):    1
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (283):       0
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (284):       0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (285):  1, 0
        libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (286):  1, 0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (287):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (288):       0
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (289):    1
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (290):    1
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (291):        1, 1, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (292):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (293):   1, 0, 0
        libinput Click Methods Available (294): 1, 1
        libinput Click Method Enabled (295):    1, 0
        libinput Click Method Enabled Default (296):    1, 0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (298):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (299):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (300):     0.000000
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (301):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (302):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (264):     1, 1
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (265):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (266):        0, 0
        Device Node (267):      "/dev/input/event4"
        Device Product ID (268):        2, 7
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (303):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (304):       1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Now please add output of `xinput list-props 12`. I almost know what is the problem, but I need to make sure. And also plese post a commnet when you do an edit to ping me.

Comment: I ran the command, and it gave information about a camera.  So I ran xinput again and noticed the id of the touchpad changed to 9.  Not sure what is up with that.  So I've posted the output of xinput list-props 9.

Comment: `libinput` is disabled by default on your system. To give you easy directions how to enable it, i need anoter output: `ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`.